# chromium's omnibox has to big font size and spans 100%

Tags: xubuntu, chromium

I just upgraded from Xubuntu 13.10 to 14.04 which comes with a new version of chromium, namely Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972). It uses the new aura design, indicated by the small blue "a" on the menu button.

Since this version the font of the omnibox/address bar is way bigger than before and additionally the omnibox spans 100% of the window now. Is this a bug or is this part of the new design?

[image: Imgur]

Comment: This is the new design of Aura.

Comment: I have the opposite problem - with the "Aura" version of Chromium that is in in 14.04, the text in the omnibox is now too tiny (on a large, hi res screen).  There doesn't seem to be any way to configure it, since it presumably looks just right on the developer's screen and they can't be bothered thinking that anybody else would want anything different.  Haven't been able to find an option to turn off this aura thing either.